# Index routes with nested routes in React-router v3

Tags: javascript, reactjs, react-router

I am planning to have the following route setup in my app. I am currently using React-Router 2.7.

```
/
/stored_systems
/stored_systems/schemas/:schema_id
/stored_systems/schemas/:schema_id/systems/:system_id
/runtime
/runtime/mainlines/:mainline_id
/runtime/mainlines/:mainline_id/valve_groups/:valve_group_id
```

I have written the router configuration as follows.

```
<Route path='/' component={App}>
  <IndexRoute component={StoredSystems} />

  <Route path='/stored_systems' component={StoredSystems} >
    <IndexRoute component={SchemasList} />
    <Route path='/stored_systems/schemas/:schema_id' component={Schema} />
    <Route path='/stored_systems/schemas/:schema_id/systems/:system_id' component={System} />
  </Route>

  <Route path='/runtime' component={Runtime} >
    <IndexRoute component={MainLinesList} />
    <Route path='/runtime/mainlines/:mainline_id' component={Mainline} />
    <Route path='/runtime/mainlines/:mainline_id/valve_groups/:valve_group_id' component={ValveGroup} />
  </Route>
</Route>
```

The StoredSystems and Runtime are stateless components which basically render {props.children}.

Now, if I go to /stored_systems, it will properly render the SchemasList component. Routes like /stored_systems/schemas/schema1 would render properly.

However, if I go to /, it will render the StoredSystems component, without its children. Well, there aren't really any children defined, because it is loading an IndexRoute.

How do I render the SchemaList inside StoredSystems when I navigate to the root?

Comment: i think it will be better for you to change your composition, as your requirements are not fulfilled by that design. try experimenting with pathless route.

Answer (score 1):

Move the `/` in your path and setup routes like

```
<Route component={App}>
  <Route path = '/' component={StoredSystems} >
     <IndexRoute component={SchemasList} />
  </Route>

  <Route path='/stored_systems' component={StoredSystems} >
    <IndexRoute component={SchemasList} />
    <Route path='/stored_systems/schemas/:schema_id' component={Schema} />
    <Route path='/stored_systems/schemas/:schema_id/systems/:system_id' component={System} />
  </Route>

  <Route path='/runtime' component={Runtime} >
    <IndexRoute component={MainLinesList} />
    <Route path='/runtime/mainlines/:mainline_id' component={Mainline} />
    <Route path='/runtime/mainlines/:mainline_id/valve_groups/:valve_group_id' component={ValveGroup} />
  </Route>
</Route>
```